# MarkLogic knowledge base

Tags: javascript, database, web, marklogic

I am supposed to do a proof of concept for my company using MarkLogic to turn flat files as well as data sources from the web to create an ODS (operational data store).

I do not have any web development experience so my company has suggested I learn javascript, node, and angular.

This is obviously a huge undertaking and I have about a weeks worth of time to get something operational.

I am wondering if someone could give me suggestions on what I should actually learn that will aid me in my MarkLogic venture.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several projects that allow you to stand up a fully functioning basic search app on top of MarkLogic in mere minutes, for instance these two:

- [slush-marklogic-node](https://github.com/marklogic/slush-marklogic-node), with a NodeJS middle-tier
- [slush-marklogic-spring-boot](https://github.com/marklogic/slush-marklogic-spring-boot), which gives you pretty much the same app, but with a Java Spring Boot middle-tier

For ingesting data, I'd suggest looking at [MLCP](http://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp) first. It has plenty possibilities.

HTH!

Comment: Awesome. Thank yoU!